# Is it possible to install amd64 software on aarch64?

Tags: 64-bit, vpn, multiarch, cpu-architecture

I have a VPN Unlimited account, and want to install it on my pinebook.

When I try using GDebi, I get the message "Status: Error: Wrong architecture 'amd64'"

Do I have to wait for the vpnto have an aarch64 release, or can I do something to get it working.

Any relevant advice much appreciated.

Other advice considered on a case by case basis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pinebook is Arm 64 bit architecture, not AMD 64. The Arm Cortex uses different instruction set as the Amd processors. Thus the binary packages are not compatible. You can contact the VPN unlimited support for the ARM 64bit package. Be sure you specify your system.